# SPF record, can additional lookups send email on my behalf

Tags: email, security, dns, spf

Looking at the hypothetical scenario with 4 domains and their following SPF records:

Domain: example.com
SPF record: v=spf1 include:otherdomain.com ~all

Domain: otherdomain.com
SPF record: v=spf1 a include:thirddomain.com ~all

Domain: thirddomain.com
SPF record: v=spf1 ip4:1.2.3.4 include:unsecuredomain.com ~all

Domain: unsecuredomain.com
SPF record: v=spf1 +all

- example.com uses otherdomain.com to send emails on its behalf and "soft fail" any other domains.
- otherdomain.com uses their own IPs to send emails and also allows thirddomain.com to send emails on its behalf and "soft fail" other domains.
- thirddomain.com uses the IP 1.2.3.4 to send emails and allows unsecuredomain.com to send emails on its behalf and "soft fail" other domains
- unsecuredomain.com allows anyone to send emails on its behalf.

Questions:
Can anyone, unsecuredomain.com, or thirddomain.com send email on behalf of example.com?
Can anyone send emails on behalf of thirddomain.com?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what you're worrying about, but it's OK: included domains' `all` policies **do not** create a back-door into your own SPF policy.

- `otherdomain.com` can send for `example.com` from wherever its `A` records point, and also from `thirddomain.com`'s literal IP.
- `thirddomain.com` can send for `example.com` from its literal IP only.
- `unsecuredomain.com` can't send for `example.com` at all.
- Any other source will get a softfail from `example.com`'s `~all` default mechanism.

It's clarified in [RFC7208 section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-5.2):

> For example, evaluating a "-all" directive in the referenced
> record does not terminate the overall processing and does not
> necessarily result in an overall "fail".

and

> With the "include" mechanism, an administratively external set of
> hosts can be authorized, but determination of sender policy is still
> a function of the original domain's SPF record (as determined by the
> "all" mechanism in that record).

In short, only the `all` mechanism for your own record is used.